# Hypothesis test for Poisson rates with stochastic time distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution

I am aiming to run some hypothesis test for a couple biological simulations. In these simulations I assume that biological mutations are accumulated at a Poisson rate proportional to time, and I want to run a hypothesis test to determine whether the rate of accumulations of mutations is different between two simulations. That is $X_1 \sim Poisson(t_1\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim Poisson(t_2 \lambda_2)$. I want to test $H_0: \lambda_1 = \lambda_2$(up to some factor). I have read some literature on this test, but it seems that most take the time factor to be a given: [https://www.smu.edu/~/media/Site/Dedman/Departments/Statistics/TechReports/TR356.ashx](https://www.smu.edu/%7E/media/Site/Dedman/Departments/Statistics/TechReports/TR356.ashx). I don't exactly know the times, but I know that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are drawn from some distribution $P$, and I know the number of events in both simulations.

Is there any approach or theoretical results that have been studied for this problem. One workaround that I was thinking of is just simply doing some sort of bootstrap test where I draw the times at random and then compute the p-value and take an average.

Comment: Do you know $P$? Are $t_1$ and $t_2$ iid?

Comment: Yes. Roughly speaking, samples from $P$ are made by a generative process, first picking a uniform, then picking from a Poisson with that parameter. Yes, they are iid.

Comment: That might suggest the $t_i$ had a discrete distribution with a positive probability of being $0$ - If the $t_i\lambda_i$ are small, then I would not expect you could have a particularly powerful test

Comment: There is likely some probability that $t_i$ is zero, although I imagine it is very small. That said $t_i \lambda_i$ could be very small in many instances, yes.